# How to communicate both ways between embedded browser and webside

Tags: javascript, c++, browser, backend

I have a C++ project for windows, using MiniBlink as embedded browser. (MiniBlink is a smaller Blink, which is close to chromium). I use this embedded browser to show responsive and nice looking dialogs with Quasar.js (wrapper for vue.js).

Problem:
Mostly a browser is just the passive backend. In my case, both the backend (project with embedded browser) and the frontend (dialog) are active and thus I need some communication. At the moment I use a local server to catch HTTP send from the frontend to the backend.

But is there a way to communicate from the backend to the frontend? At the moment I could only think about catching cookies or using a permanent loop in JS to send http queries to check for a possible response.

And is there no other way to send information to a backend? Everything is local, I dont need nor really want to send it into the network.

Thanks!

Comment: Use Websockets.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like exactly what I was searching for. Now I just need to find an implementation for quasar/vue and a c++ library/further instructions/tutorial how to handle a websocket. Since the connection is supposed to stay alive, i guess, that websocket server should be in its own thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CertainPerformance added as a comment, WebSockets might be the best way to go.
If one does not like to implement a websocket server, because a http server is already running, long polling requests might be the best workaround to simulate this behaviour.

Long polling: The client sends a request, which stays open as long as possible. If the server needs to communicate, it can use the open request to send its own "request" via response. It is a bit hacky, but essentially the idea behind websockets.

Mozilla has a nice article to help with websockets: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

If you (like me) use vuejs or quasar, you might want have a look at vue-native-websocket.
https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: Use a local temp file to save on one side and read on other (can be also used both way)

Idea 2 (similar to question author solution): Local server with both side communication (GET/POST request into one side, text/json other way around)

Idea 3: Use launch parameter to pass though data directly into links for example: instead of using browserprocess.exe file.html, use browserprocess.exe file.html#showsomething

There are also other ways which like catching for example: checking window title of process with certain binary name from running tasks by other side; we didin't get good enough info about your background becouse you coud either use it in same process or other process, if thats same process you coud also just directly use variables both ways directly in code of miniblink and do action when they meet if statement

Comment: Idea 1: Might be the easiest solution (technically) but I don't really like it, because I would need the rights to write files on the target system, which might be prevented by anti virus or similar.
Idea 2: I use this and it works reasonably well, but only for frontend to backend. I can not initiate communication from server to frontend.
Idea 3: As you said this is only initialisation, but after that no communication is possible.

I am not sure how exactly miniblink works internally, I dont use a sepperate process. I dread to recompile miniblink though. ;-)